# How to implement CachedExpr in VTD-xml Parser

Tags: vtd-xml

I want to load all the XPath and the variables in the CachedExpr at once and use it for multiple times. is anyone can provide samples for adding variables and XPath in CachedExpr and also let me know how to declare the XPathNamespace in it.

```
public class VTDParser {
private final CustomAutoPilot autoPilot;

public static class CustomAutoPilot extends com.ximpleware.AutoPilot {
    final Hashtable<String, com.ximpleware.Expr> variables = new Hashtable<>();

    public CustomAutoPilot() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomAutoPilot(VTDNav v) {
        super(v);
    }

    public void declareVariableExpr(String varName, String varExpr) throws XPathParseException {
        try {
            parser p = new parser(new StringReader(varExpr));
            p.nsHash = nsHash;
            p.symbolHash = variables;
            xpe = (com.ximpleware.Expr) p.parse().value;
            variables.put(varName, xpe);
            ft = true;
        } catch ( XPathParseException e ) {
            throw e;
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            throw new XPathParseException("Error occurred");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectXPath(String s) throws XPathParseException {
        try {
            parser p = new parser(new StringReader(s));
            p.nsHash = nsHash;
            p.symbolHash = variables;
            xpe = (com.ximpleware.Expr) p.parse().value;
            ft = true;
            if ( enableCaching )
                xpe.markCacheable();
        } catch ( XPathParseException e ) {
            throw e;
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            throw new XPathParseException("");
        }
    }

    public VTDNav getNavigationObject() {
        return vn;
    }
}

public VTDParser(String message) throws ParseException {
    try {
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        byte[] content = message.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
        vg.setDoc(content);
        vg.parse(true);
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        autoPilot = new CustomAutoPilot(vn);
        autoPilot.declareXPathNameSpace("prefix", "http://www.w3.org");
    } catch ( ParseException e ) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public String asString(String xpath) throws XPathParseException {
    try {
        autoPilot.selectXPath(xpath);
        return autoPilot.evalXPathToString().trim();
    } catch ( XPathParseException e ) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public void variable(String name, String value) throws XPathParseException {
    try {
        autoPilot.declareVariableExpr(name, value);
    } catch ( XPathParseException e ) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, XPathParseException {
    String xml = "<tree><fruit> Mango</fruit></tree>";
    VTDParser parser = new VTDParser(xml);
    System.out.println(parser.asString("//tree/fruit"));
}
```

}

We have wrote CustomAutopilot class which is parsing successfully. WE ant o compile the list of xpath in CachedExpr and reuse it instead of compiling each time.

Comment: I dont think CachedExpr is something you interact with directly... once it is turned on (which it is by default) it will work as you indicated by default... XPathNamespace is declared with AutoPilot... like any regular xpath evaluation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be mistaking the purpose of cached expression... The goal of cachedExpr is **not** to persist compiled XPath in memory for subsequent reuse ...

Its purpose is to cache the output of previous evaluated XPath evaluation result (typically of those absolute expressions) when those results are needed multiple times but you don't want to waste cycles for each re-evaluation.

Consider the following expression:

//a[text()=//b]

for every evaluation of //a you will need to evaluate the predicate [text()=//b]... so what cache expression will save the result of //b and reuse it for subsequent predicate evaluation...

If your goal is to persist pre-compiled XPath expression... my suggestion is to use a hash map (or table) you could use xpath string as key and autoPilot as value... but there are many ways to do this...

Comment: we are tying to improve the performance of parsing the xpath. On more question is there any other way we can use the create or load the index on the fly instead of writing into a physical file into the disk ?.

Comment: performance of parsing xpath only matters if you deal with small xml files or looping... always precompile the xpath ... never put it in a loop... precompile and reuse (ie. calling autoPilot.resetXPath())....

Comment: creating and loading index always refers to the persistence aspect of VTD... in other words, it is always about reading and writing to disk (HD or flash)... if you don't garbage collect the output of parsing, which means it is gonna occupy RAM space... there is no index reading to speak of in the first place, right?

Comment: Is there any method available to trim the result of following method autoPilot.evalXPathToString(). We are doing trimming the spaces at both end using the String method. Do we have any method at VTDNav ? .
I saw a enableIgnoredWhiteSpace method in VTDGen class . Wha tit is used for ?

Comment: Since you are only talking about the trimming of one string val... I don't think it makes a whole lot of differences... yes I think VTDNav has a method that does something to that effect called toStringNormalized()... but really except for printing out debugging message, I want you to ask yourself... why do you need to perform such string actuating operation in the first space... the whole point of VTD is such operations are rarely needed for your app to function... think about that for a moment